# Check each value in one DataFrame, if it is less than variable replace value in another DataFrame(same size) on same place with 0

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

So I have 2 dataframes. One with values, and the second one with test statistic(TS) values. I need to check each cell in TS dataframe and if its value is smaller than 1, I need to change value in the second dataframe on same cell to 0.

[image: Two dataframes]

I've tried to map them but could not find the right way.

```
yearly_flux = yearly_flux.map(lambda x : 0 ts_yearly_flux else x, ts_yearly_flux)
```

Have no idea if I can solve it like this, but I've tryed.

It's my second question so sorry if something is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(5,10)))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(5,10)))

df2[:] = np.where(df1 < 1, 0, df2)
```